# How to encrypt user profile in DNN

Tags: encryption, dotnetnuke

I am new to DotNetNuke and using DNN 6.x.

I want to encrypt all the data in user profile so that if someone steals the database he will not be able to use profile of my users.

Is there any module available for doing this or what are the alternates.

One thing that I came across is TDE but SQLServerExpress2008 does not support this feature. :(

Answer (score 0):

If you arent going to go to something like SQL Server Enterprise you are going to have to write a user provider yourself (or have a contractor do it for you) that does encryption and decryption for you.

Encrypting the user data can be a huge undertaking and depending on how you do it the process can put a load on your system. I would carefully consider if you really need to encrypt the data. Perhaps you could have a call to another provider that could be more secure for the profile like active directory.